# I want to access object properties which are dynamically set at run time

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know if this question is easy or hard. But I am still learning and finding it hard. 
I have object called as '**positions**' inside there is an another object '**item**' and then array '**top,left**'.

The item is dynamically added and it is html element. **positions** is an **object**

```
{item_1_1: Object, item_1_2: Object, item_2_1: Object, item_2_2: Object}
```

This **item_**... has position of **Top** and **Left** values.
The object of '**position**' object can even change as below, as it is dynamically changed.

```
{item_1_1: Object, item_1_2: Object,item_1_3: Object, item_2_1: Object, item_2_2: Object,item_2_3: Object}
```

Or so on with

```
{item_1_1: Object, item_2_1: Object}
```

Now coming to my question part. How can I access these item of different _1_1 or _1_2 or so on... I need to access these item's position of left and top. But problem is items can be 'n' number. I wanted a code to access dynamically.

```
aryAns=[];
for(var i in positions)
    {           
        aryAns.push("positions.item"+i);
        for(var j=0;j<aryAns.length;j++){

        }
    }
```

I know the above code is not right, but I am confused. Can you help me out.

Comment: so this object contains objects and is called positions? {item_1_1: Object, item_1_2: Object, item_2_1: Object, item_2_2: Object}

Answer (score 0):

You can access object properties like this:

```
objectName[propString]
```

The for...in loop iterates through these property names, so, in your example it would be:

```
for(var i in positions) {
    var item = positions[i];
    // access to item

    // now you can also access members of these item objects
    var top = item.top;
    var left = item.left; 
    }
}
```